# Node Update Causes Package Path Export Error

Tags: node.js, iis

I just updated Node on my local and remote machines only to find this error whenever I upload my app to the remote IIS machine. It is from an Apify dependency called entities. Since this only happens on the server I have no idea what is wrong.

[ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/decode_codepoint' is not defined by "exports"

Comment: You need to edit the question to show the exact steps on "I upload my app to the remote IIS machine". Besides, what do you exactly mean by saying you "updated Node"? From which version to which version?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your problem clearly. please post more details information about your issue.